# How can I add CSS class when I click on React?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, styled-components, recoiljs

My development environment: `react`, `recoil`, `javascript`, `styled-component`.

When I click on the technology stack for each field classified as a tab, I want to change the CSS only when it is clicked and included in the selected Tags.

[image]

```js
const [selectedTags, setSelectedTags] = useRecoilState(selectedTagsState);

  const tabContArr = [
    {
      tabTitle: 'FE',
      tabCont: ['JavaScript', 'TypeScript', 'React', 'Vue', 'Svelte', 'Nextjs'],
    },
    {
      tabTitle: 'BE',
      tabCont: [
        'Java',
        'Spring',
        'Nodejs',
        'Nextjs',
        'Go',
        'Kotlin',
        'Express',
        'MySQL',
        'MongoDB',
        'Python',
        'Django',
        'php',
        'GraphQL',
        'Firebase',
      ],
    },
    {
      tabTitle: 'etc',
      tabCont: [],
    },
    
  ];

  const onTagClick = (e) => {
    const newSelectedTags = [...selectedTags];

    const filterTarget = newSelectedTags.filter(
      (el) => el.tagName === e.target.textContent,
    );

    if (filterTarget.length === 0 && newSelectedTags.length < 5) {
      let tagObj = {};
      tagObj.tagName = e.target.textContent;
      newSelectedTags.push(tagObj);
      setSelectedTags(newSelectedTags);
    } else if (
      filterTarget.length !== 0 ||
      selectedTags.length >= 5
    ) {
      {
        (''); // nothing change
      }
    }
  };

          // FE, BE Choose
          tabContArr[activeIdx].tabCont.map((skillTag, idx) => {
            return (
              <div
                key={idx}
                className={
                  // HERE!!!
                  selectedTags.includes(skillTag)
                    ? 'skill-tag skill-selected-tag'
                    : 'skill-tag'
                }
                onClick={onTagClick}
                aria-hidden="true"
              >
                {skillTag}
              </div>
            );
          })
```

I tried to write the code like the one marked "HERE!!!" but it didn't work when I did this. Please help me on how to change the CSS (Class) only for the names in the selected Tag!!

```js
className={
  // HERE!!!
  selectedTags.includes(skillTag)
    ? 'skill-tag skill-selected-tag'
    : 'skill-tag'
  }
```

Comment: you can create an array with useState and get the initial state from the skilltags array and add a key to the skill tag and name it active whenever a user clicked on the tags to make it true
and then you can set tag to active or the active if you need to

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `tabContArr[activeIdx].tabCont.map((skillTag, idx) => {`, `skillTag` is a string, while `selectedTags` is an array of objects, like this: `[{tagName: 'Java'}, {tagName: 'Spring'}, ...]`.
You are determining whether the array of objects contains a string, which will  never occur. `console.log(selectedTags, skillTag)` will make it easier to understand.

Comment: You explained it easily, so I understood it very well.
I solved the problem!!!
Thank you so much!

Comment: @2seb2 you should mark this answer correct if it solved your problem (it's the big green tick by the side of the answer).